# How do you join multiple lines in a python file

Tags: python-3.x, string, generator, file-handling, yield

below is the code to remove comments from a file and join the line if they end with '\', this works for most of the test cases but does not for one:

```
from typing import Any, List, Optional, Sequence, Iterator

def get_lines(path: str) -> Iterator[str]:

    """ Function to print lines of a given file and remove comments"""

    output=''
    filehandle = open(path, 'r')
    lines = filehandle.readline()
    for lines in filehandle:
    
        if lines.startswith('#'):
            while lines.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
                next_line = next(filehandle)
                lines = lines.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line
            continue
        else:

            while lines.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
                next_line = next(filehandle)
                lines = lines.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line
            output += lines
            output = lines.split("#",1)
            lines = output[0]
        while lines.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
            next_line = next(filehandle)
            lines = lines.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line

        yield lines
```

Below is the input file:

```
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line0>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line1># comment
<line2>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line3.1 \ #world 
line3.2 \#hello
line3.3>
<line4.1 \ #comment
line4.2>
<line5># comment \
# more comment1 \
more comment2>
<line6>
# here's a comment line continued to the next line \
this line is part of the comment from the previous line
```

I get the below output when I run the code:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 line3.2 \#hello
line3.3>
<line4.1 line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

Expected Output:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>
<line4.1 line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

What do I do to fix this?